# redis-server does not start when parsed path to configfile

Tags: redis

I'm having a Raspberry Pi 4, which I want to run a redis-server (v.5) on (used for Celery in a Django application).

The issue is, I can't get access to the redis server from my computer (they are on the same network).

I think the issue is that the config-file is not loaded when I run `redis-server` (it says so in the messages when the server starts and running `redis-cli; INFO server` also shows `config-file:`. If I parse the path to the config file e.g `redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf` (it has 644 access) then nothing happens; no error, no warning, no server start, no nothing. Just a new command line in the terminal.

I can't find anything about this issue - any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does the /etc/redis/redis.conf file define the location of a logfile where the redis-server process may be writing useful messages?

Comment: you can check your log file. you can find this in config file. the default address is `/var/log/redis/redis-server.log` but